# Extract data from google adwords

Tags: google-ads-api

I would like to extract cost data from google adwords and insert into our data warehouse. 
What would be the easiest way to achieve it? 
I am looking for the following information.

AccountDescriptiveName,CampaignName, AdGroupName, Id,Headline, Clicks, Impressions,Ctr, AverageCpc, AverageCpm, Cost, Conversions, ConversionRate, CostPerConversion

I am new to APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the AdWords API I suggest that you save the data into a Google Drive Spreadsheet and then you access it from your server.

Example of saving AdWords data to spreadsheet:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/examples/reports

Google Drive Spreadsheet API:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/